# Web scraping wrong return

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am  trying to web **scrape** with Python Beautiful soup. I wanted to get data from the English Premier League, see the page below. After this code, my return didn't match to the data in the website.
Please review and help. I suspect this is maybe due to pagination – I wanted to pull out EPL 2017/18 data on 'wins'.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json 

url = "https://www.premierleague.com/stats/top/clubs/wins?se=79T"
data = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

PLtable = soup.find_all('table')[0]
data = []
for td in PLtable.find_all("td"):
    data.append(td.text.replace('\n', ' ').strip())
```

Comment: If you run print(soup.prettify()) it will show all the HTML that was retrieved from the site. Does it include HTML?

Comment: Thanks, yes 
!DOCTYPE html,  that is what  i get. However, the data the is extracted is completely different from what is in the webpage

Comment: That will most likely be because the web page generates the content using JavaScript. Request / Beautiful Soup can't handle this. One approach is to use selenium or if possible call the APIs directly.

Answer (score 1):

Data loaded via api in json format. see the api url in below code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

import json

url = 'https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/stats/ranked/teams/wins?page=0&pageSize=20&compSeasons=79&comps=1&altIds=true'

headers = {
    "Host": "footballapi.pulselive.com",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0",
"Accept": "*/*",
"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
"Origin": "https://www.premierleague.com",
"Connection": "keep-alive",
"Referer": "https://www.premierleague.com/stats/top/clubs/wins?se=79",
"If-None-Match": "083bcdbc679be42363d2eaefe7e90df5b",
"TE": "Trailers",


}

results = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

for data in results['stats']['content']:
    print(data['owner']['name'], data['value'])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ,I am using Jupyter online, not able to get webdriver

Comment: webdriver in selenium , I have not used selenium here.

Comment: please mark answer as accepted if it correctly solved your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Improving your question would help to make it easier for all to understand and help.

**What is going on?**

- You try to fetch the statistics for a special time period and your code works well
- Problem is that the website is rendering in default the statistics not in your period, it is rendering over all seasons and filters the statistics a second later.
- Request do not get this, it still will get the statistics over all seasons

**What you can do is using selenium - Simple example**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

url = 'https://www.premierleague.com/stats/top/clubs/wins?se=79T'

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get(url)

sleep(5)

soup=BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source,"html.parser")
PLtable = soup.find('tbody', class_='statsTableContainer')

data = []
for td in PLtable.find_all("td"):
      data.append(td.text.replace('\n', ' ').strip()) 
print(data)

browser.close()
```

**Output**

```
['1.', 'Leicester City', '9', '', '2.', 'Liverpool', '9', '', '3.', 'Everton', '8', '', '4.', 'Manchester United', '8', '', '5.', 'Aston Villa', '7', '', '6.', 'Southampton', '7', '', '7.', 'Tottenham Hotspur', '7', '', '8.', 'Chelsea', '6', '', '9.', 'Manchester City', '6', '', '10.', 'West Ham United', '6', '', '11.', 'Wolverhampton Wanderers', '6', '', '12.', 'Crystal Palace', '5', '', '13.', 'Leeds United', '5', '', '14.', 'Newcastle United', '5', '', '15.', 'Arsenal', '4', '', '16.', 'Brighton and Hove Albion', '2', '', '17.', 'Burnley', '2', '', '18.', 'Fulham', '2', '', '19.', 'West Bromwich Albion', '1', '']
```